# Docker Compose can't find Docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose (the Java library) to run Docker. However, I keep getting the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find docker, looked in: DockerCommandLocations{possiblePaths=[null, /usr/local/bin/docker, /usr/bin/docker]}
```

My docker executable is in usr/local/bin and my docker compose executable is in usr/bin. Why would this be happening?

EDIT: I have found that the library is running:

```
new File(<eachDockerLocation>).exists();
```

where eachDockerLocation is "/usr/bin/docker" and "/usr/local/bin/docker". For both of these cases, false is returned, meaning that Java cannot see them for some reason. Why would this be?

EDIT2:
I tried running a new File.exists() in a test project in IntelliJ and it returned the same thing. However, when run in a terminal it returns true. So it's the IDE that's not working here.
What is also interesting is that when I check file.exists("/usr/bin") in IDE, it returns true. But if I run file.exists("/usr/bin/docker") in IDE, it's false.

Comment: did you try it with root privileges?

Comment: Make sure that your user is in the group `docker` (by running `groups` command in the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this was Flatpak. As Flatpak runs things in a sandbox as far as I know, IntelliJ was not seeing the actual environment and therefore could not find files that were there on the actual machine.

So I'd recommend to **not use the Flatpak version of IntelliJ**.